# Issue when using prefetch as opposed to local in typeahead.js

Tags: jquery, local, typeahead.js, typeahead, prefetch

My code is working fine with local data, but if I copy the local data to a json file and use the prefetch option it doesn't work, it just returns an undefined list.

I'd like to use prefetched data and listen to the custom event handle typeahead:selected to populate multiple input fields. Any suggestion to fix this issue? Thanks.

My code is here:

```
  <form>
<input type="text" class="typeahead" id="subject_label" /><br/>
<input type="text"  id="subject_id" /><br/>
</form>
var s = [{"id":"1234","label":"fish"},{"id":"5678","label":"histo"}]

var labels = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.label);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    //  local option is working  
    //  local: s
    // If using prefetch url option with exactly same dataset, the code is broken, I'm  
    //sure the url format is correct.
     prefetch: '/sample.json'

});

labels.initialize();

var subjectLabelTypeahead = $('#subject_label.typeahead');
var subjectIdTypeahead = $('#subject_id');

// Initialise typeahead 
subjectLabelTypeahead.typeahead({
    highlight: true
}, {
    name: 'label',
    displayKey: 'label',
    source: labels.ttAdapter()
});

// Set-up event handlers so that the ID is auto-populated when select label 
var subjectLabelItemSelectedHandler = function (e, datum) {
    subjectIdTypeahead.val(datum.id);
};

subjectLabelTypeahead.on('typeahead:selected', subjectLabelItemSelectedHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "prefetch" value should reference a javascript object instead of the URL string (see the documentation [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#prefetch)).

Try changing it to this:

```
var labels = new Bloodhound({
 datumTokenizer: function (d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.label);
 },
 queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
 prefetch: {
  url: '/sample.json',
  filter: function(items) {
   return $.map(items, function(item) { 
    return { 
     label: item.label,
     id: item.id }; 
   });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried the same solution before and it didn't work. This time it works, that's strange. Thank you!